Is a nonzero multilinear functional an open mapping?
Let $X$ be a normed space over a field $K$ (of  $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) and $f: X^n \rightarrow K$ be a $n$-linear map, $f \neq 0$. It is know that if $n=1$ $f$ it is an open mapping. Is it still true for $n>1$?

Pick any $(x_1, \dots, x_n)=x\in X^n$ such that $\Vert x\Vert=1$ and $f(x)\neq 0$. Wlog $x_1\neq 0$ (otherwise pick any other nonzero entry). Then consider $$g:K\rightarrow K, t\rightarrow f(tx_1, x_2, \dots, x_n).$$ This map is linear and nonzero, hence, open.
The image of $f$ contains the image of $g$ and hence $f$ is surjective.
Let now $y\in K^n$. To show that $f$ is open we only need to show that for every $r>0$ we have that $f(y)$ is in the interior of $f(B_r(y))$. However, we have
$$B_r(y)\supseteq y+\{r(tx_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \ : \ \vert t \vert \in [0,1)\}.$$
Thus, $f(B_r(y))$ contains
$$y+ r^n g(B_1^K(0))$$
which finishes the proof as $g$ is open.

@Adayah I am a bit puzzled by your statement. Multilinear maps for me are maps which are linear in every coordinate. Which definition do you use?

Forget it, I missed the "$n$-" before "linear".
